# How to use Min() and Max() in Linq SQL queries

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I am trying to translate this SQL query to link but can't figure out how to use `Min()` and `Max()` in the right way

```
SELECT
    MIN(r.[TimeStamp]) AS [TimeStamp], 
    r.ExerciseId, r.UserId, 
    MAX(r.Pr) AS Pr, 
    e.Name, u.FirstName, u.LastName, e.SubHeader, e.PrType
FROM
    [Record] r, Exercise e, [User] u
WHERE
    e.Id = r.ExerciseId 
    AND u.Id = r.UserId 
GROUP BY
    r.ExerciseId, r.UserId, e.Name, u.FirstName, u.LastName, e.SubHeader, e.PrType
```

Comment: Side note; It's *2022*; the ANSI-92 explicit JOIN syntax has been around for *30 years* now. It's really *long past time* you adopted it: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: I usually put entire query in parenthesis (from ....).Select(x => new {min = x.Min(y => y.Pr)}).ToList()